# I'm getting an error message when making migration to db in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, migration, makemigrations

hello guys I'm doing a django tutorial and i missed a change the instructor did in models.py so i fix it but when trying to make the migration to the db it gives me a code that I don't understand or i don't know what to do, here is what it says:

`(tonyto) PS E:\web-dev\Python\Django1\myappito> python manage.py makemigrations`

```
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

they way it was
`name: models.CharField(max_length=100)     details: models.CharField(max_length=500)`

and this is how i update it
`name: models.CharField(max_length=100)     details: models.CharField(max_length=500)`
thank you in advance.

Comment: Press 1 from the keyboard. Django will replace all the existing rows with a null values. If you find this answer, helpful please mark it as the solution.

Comment: it will be helpful to share new field you have added  which casing the migration

Comment: my code was this way  ```name: models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details: models.CharField(max_length=500)```  and now is like this ```name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=500)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused because you're trying to migrate a model field that cannot be null, but since it cannot be null, it needs a default value so that django can replace all the existing rows with the null value of that field.

You have two options:

1. Provide the default by hand, and the django it's going to replace all the null values of that field with this
2. Set a default value in the model, example:

`number = models.IntegerField(default=1)`

`string = models.CharField(default='')`

Comment: yes that's what I tried but is not budging and  I dont get what values is asking for i tried option one and two

Comment: this is correct answer but you need to remove the last file create by makemigration and run makemigration again after adding this answer

Comment: ok cool so if i get it right , what you mean is to go to the folder and delete the file made by makemigrations and then do the process all over again with the updated values ???

Answer (score 1):

## first approach

- this comes because you run the migration on each field created so the previous created filled doesn't accept null value so you want to provide default value in your case it is string value
- you can choose the first choice and but the answer to be "default" with a quotation to understand it as a string

## The second solution

delete the latest file created in the migration folder and
modify your model to be

```
'''
name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True) 
details = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True) 
'''
```

then run the migration again

> > python manage.py makemigration
> > python manage.py migrate
> > then go back to model again and remove null from each field and run
> > python manage.py makemigration
> > python manage.py migrate